# Correct use of Schema.org "ImageObject"

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I have doubts about the correct use of schema ImageObject.

I have a small image and a link to view it in larger size, but I don’t know exactly which of these three forms is the right one.

```
<span itemprop='image' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/ImageObject'>
<a href='big_1280x720.jpg' itemprop='contentUrl'><img src='small_90x60.jpg' itemprop='image'></a>
</span>

<span itemprop='image' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/ImageObject'>
<a href='big_1280x720.jpg' itemprop='image'><img src='small_90x60.jpg' itemprop='thumbnailUrl'></a>
</span>

<span itemprop='image' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/ImageObject'>
<a href='big_1280x720.jpg' itemprop='contentUrl'><img src='small_90x60.jpg' itemprop='thumbnailUrl'></a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The third one removing the first occurence of *itemprop='image'* is the right one.

```
<div itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/ImageObject'>
  <a href='big_1280x720.jpg' itemprop='contentUrl'>
    <img src='small_90x60.jpg' itemprop='thumbnailUrl'>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: If an image is a part of a bigger scope (e. g. a movie), then removing `itemprop="image"` will extract it from the current scope to the root one. Check https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Comment: Also compare against the [Yandex structured data tool](https://webmaster.yandex.com/tools/microtest/) for balance.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe someone finds this question while searching for "how to use Schema.org ImageObject", as I did, so, just for reference, here is an example from the Schema.org documentation:

> ## Without markup:
>
> ```
> <h2>Beach in Mexico</h2>
> <img src="mexico-beach.jpg" alt="Sunny, sandy beach."/>
> By Jane Doe
> Photographed in Puerto Vallarta, Mexico
> Date uploaded: Jan 25, 2008
> I took this picture while on vacation last year.
> ```
>
> ## Microdata:
>
> ```
> <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
>   <h2 itemprop="name">Beach in Mexico</h2>
>   <img src="mexico-beach.jpg"
>   alt="Sunny, sandy beach."
>   itemprop="contentUrl" />
>   By <span itemprop="author">Jane Doe</span>
>   Photographed in
>     <span itemprop="contentLocation">Puerto Vallarta, Mexico</span>
>   Date uploaded:
>     <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2008-01-25">Jan 25, 2008
>   <span itemprop="description">I took this picture while on vacation last year.</span>
> </div>
> ```

http://schema.org/ImageObject#examples

Comment: Examples do not cover use of `thumbnailUrl` as asked in the question.